# How does Next JS application works on browser even without .html file in folder structure?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, next.js

*Sorry if this is some stupid question*
But How does applications built in NextJS communicate with browsers as there is no .html file in the folder structure after creating `npx create-next-app`.

Comment: Fundamentally, because the necessary HTML files are generated by the Next.js build process.

Comment: When building the app (`next build`), Next.js creates a `.next` folder which contains the HTML files that are served.

Answer (score 5):

The `index.html` file is created after running `next build`.

#### The files

The code that you write for Next.js is kind of an *abstraction* of the website you want to serve in the end.

That means you are writing Javascript code in an easy, convenient way, which has to follow the rules that
Next.js has specified. Then you are telling Next.js to compile your code (`next build`),
and Next.js creates the actual website based on your Javascript code.

The website files are created inside the folder `/.next`, the location of the `index.html` is `/.next/server/pages/index.html`.
(see [Next.js Build API](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment)).

*(Also note that there might be no index.html file at all, depending on the specified routing and build process. Also the location of the files should be considered an implementation detail, theoretically Next.js might change this behavior at any version upgrade.)*

#### The server

Next.js also provides its own [node server](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#nodejs-server), so if you call `next start` (after `next build`) it will start its own server,
which just knows where to look for the files.

Next.js also defines some routing behind the scenes (based on your `/pages` folder), which is (kind of)
the reason why you are not seeing any `index.html` in the address bar of the browser.

#### Static files

If you are using [`next export`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) instead of `next start`, then Next.js will create static files,
and you will find a folder which contains `.html` files and all the stuff that you probably were expecting to see, and
which can be served by some other static file server. (*For this you have to remove at least the `<Image>` from the project created by `create-next-app`, because of the [limitations of `next export`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features)*)

#### Remark about `index.html`

So we found where Next.js creates an `index.html` file, but also note that - while it makes sense to follow conventions - it would actually
not even be necessary to have an `index.html` file if you are writing your own server, e.g.:

```
// - save as 'server.js',
// - run 'node server.js'
// - open 'http://localhost:8888/abc' in the browser

const http = require("http");
const url = require("url");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.write('<html><body>you called the url:' + request.url + '</body></html>');
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```