# Use index.js file in Next.js as homepage or only as starting point?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I wonder if I should implement my homepage directly inside the index.js file, or if I should create a seperate "home-page.js" file in the pages folder. Is the index.js file merely the starting point for the application or should I use it as a page itself? Or should I just redirect from index.js to my homepage? What are the different use cases for the index.js file in next.js vs react.js? I do not have any experiences and would like to hear some best practices or things to look out for.

Comment: I think the index file directly maps to the `/` URL, so if you did use `home-page` then the URL for the home page would have to be `/home-page`? I'm not sure I see the advantage of doing that.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I agree. It seems a bit overcomplicated to me as well. I am just asking myself if it would be a bad thing if the index.js file would become too large when I import a lot of components or if this is the purpose of this file and the name is just a default-name for next to find the root file

Comment: The name is also the path, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 10):

*(I assume that you mean the Next.js file `/pages/index.js`)*

You should use the Next.js `/pages/index.js` file as a page itself *<sup>(1)</sup>*, i.e. as the page for the route `http://localhost:3000`,
just the same as you would use e.g. `/pages/about.js` for the route `http://localhost:3000/about`.

The `index.js` files in Next.Js and in pure React are actually completely different, unrelated files:

1. React `index.js` is the entry point for the apps javascript execution (or "starting point" how you called it).
2. Next.js `pages/index.js` is the default route. It corresponds to the `index.html` of static webages, i.e. the page that comes up if you type e.g. `http://localhost:3000` (without any page name) in the browsers address bar.

Next.js doesn't have any "entry point `index.js`" file at all (in the folders you are editing),
instead all the final `.js` files will only be generated inside the `.next` folder when you start `next build`.

See also:

- [How does Next JS application works on browser even without .html file in folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70641546/how-does-next-js-application-works-on-browser-even-without-html-file-in-folder/70656760#70656760))
- [Why does create-react-app creates both App.js and index.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493069/why-does-create-react-app-creates-both-app-js-and-index-js)

*<sup>(1)</sup> I don't have any opinion about if you should use the /index.js directly, or redirect to e.g. /home, or avoid using /index.js altogether. Here I just try to explain what the /index.js file does, because I think that is what the question was actually asking.*

Comment: What an amazing explanation, thank you. That really helped!